# How to concatenate consecutive rows of each group and make them as columns in dataframe and count the occurrences for each group?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
id     actions

1s       Aaa 

1s       Bbb

1s       Ccc

1s       Bbb

1s       Ccc

2s       Aaa

2s       Ddd

2s       Ddd

2s       Aaa

2s       Bbb
```

I would like something like this:

```
id  Aaa->Bbb    Bbb->Ccc   Ccc->Bbb   Aaa->Ddd   Ddd->Ddd   Ddd->Aaa

1s    1          2            1          0       0           0

2s    1          0            0          1       1           1
```

How can I achieve this? I tried some code but it did not work exactly as I want.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your code please .

Comment: Is ordering of columns important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) and [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for pairs and yhen reshape by  with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['id'],df.groupby('id')['actions'].shift().str.cat(df['actions'],sep='->'))
print (df)
actions  Aaa->Bbb  Aaa->Ddd  Bbb->Ccc  Ccc->Bbb  Ddd->Aaa  Ddd->Ddd
id                                                                 
1s              1         0         2         1         0         0
2s              1         1         0         0         1         1
```